# не поддерживается формат .aar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

Коллеги, помогите!

Я пытаюсь добавить в проект локальный `.aar`-файл так, как описано вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051137/update-module-created-from-local-aar). Стандартным путём (через Project Structure) пока не хочу пользоваться, потому что библиотека всё еще постоянно отлаживается и редактируется.

В "проектном" файле `build.gradle` я добавила ссылку на папку libs как на хранилище

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Приложение и библиотека в моем случае имеют по два варианта компилляции (flavours) - на тестовом сервере и на продукционном. Схлопываю я их, соответственно, по парам.

В файле `build.gradle`, относящемся в приложению, я добавила блок `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '**/*.aar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    alphaTestCompile files ('libs/myLib-alphaTest-release.aar')//тестовый flavour
    myReleaseCompile files('libs/myLib-myRelease-release.aar')//продукционный flavour
}
```

Каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь всё пересобрать, я получаю эту ошибку:

```
Error:Project myApp: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: C:\Users\...\myApp\libs\myLib-myRelease-release.aar
```

Я пыталась, как советовали в похожих темах, поменять формат зависимости на такой

```
alphaTestCompile  ('my.package:libs/myLib-alphaTest-release:0.1@aar')
```

и на такой

```
alphaTestCompile  (name:'myLib-alphaTest-release', ext:'aar')
```

Но в этих случаях gradle даже не может найти нужные файлы. И всё равно выдет ошибку, указанную выше.

Как мне все-таки скомпилировать этот `.aar`?